# how to use estat vif in the right way

Tags: command, regression, stata

I have 2 questions concerning `estat vif` to test multicollinearity:

1. Is it correct that you can only calculate `estat vif` after the regress command?
2. If I execute this command Stata only gives me the `vif` of one independent variable.

   - How do I get the `vif` of all the independent variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is relevant here as it is everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. I find `estat vif` documented under `regress postestimation`. If you can find it documented under any other postestimation heading, then it is applicable after that command.

Q2. You don't give any examples, reproducible or otherwise, of your problem. But `estat vif` by default gives a result for each predictor (independent variable).

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress mpg weight price

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 71)        =     66.85
       Model |  1595.93249         2  797.966246   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  847.526967        71  11.9369995   R-squared       =    0.6531
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6434
       Total |  2443.45946        73  33.4720474   Root MSE        =     3.455

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |  -.0058175   .0006175    -9.42   0.000    -.0070489   -.0045862
       price |  -.0000935   .0001627    -0.57   0.567     -.000418    .0002309
       _cons |   39.43966   1.621563    24.32   0.000     36.20635    42.67296
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estat vif

    Variable |       VIF       1/VIF  
-------------+----------------------
       price |      1.41    0.709898
      weight |      1.41    0.709898
-------------+----------------------
    Mean VIF |      1.41
```

Comment: thanks I made the mistake to put the command `estat vif` before the `regress` command.